# What is the point of a body tag if divs exist

Tags: html, wrapper

From what I can tell, `<body>` tags and `<div>` tags are exactly the same  with one key difference. You can only have one valid body tag in a document. what is the logic of using a body tag if you can use `<div class='body'>` instead?

Comment: `<div class='body'>` and `<body>` arent the same thing, the `<body>` tag tells the html which bit of the code/markup is supposed to be displayed, whereas `<div class='body'>` applies a class which can be used for css and also for html query selection

Comment: however, if i write an html document with noting but `<p>exampletext</p>` it renders fine on 99% of all browsers, excluding maybe Konqueror and some old versions of IE

Comment: Just because the browsers do their best to render it, you have issues like semantics and SEO to think of

Comment: you just have to write your code a small amount differently. does java have to have a special tag around everything except for x content, and what contains it?(ie, html tag and head tag) that you can only have one of in every java document? at this point the body tag organises everything that takes up space(except for the title) on the page into another tab that is usually very messy to sift through, though you find the occasional exception. i often see people adding the body tag because they feel they HAVE to.

Comment: You're right - this is a perfectly legit question. However, that fact does not prevent the drive-bys from exercising their daily entitlement to serial downvoting. Bottom line: if you ask anything other than a "My-code-doesn't-work-here-it-is" type of question, you will almost certainly be downvoted. Should that stop you? I say ***Nay Nay!*** but you might say *Ouch!*

Comment: that makes this community a bunch of of "hows" rather than "whys" and to understand the how, you need to know the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you're overlooking the history. When TBL developed HTML [out of the SGML spec](https://www.streetdirectory.com/etoday/history-of-htmland-sgml-ucjpoa.html) (which itself was the ISO's standardized form of ANSI's GCA that developed out of IBM's own in-house GML)... *putting content onto a screen was only part of the job.*

[TBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) is also the guy who figured out using text domain names and TLD extensions to stand-in for the numeric IP addresses of servers on the net. He then had to figure out how to give a vast array of different machines, from different manufacturers, running disparate OSs, the ability to display the information as similarly as possible. *See how far back this subject must reach?*

Anyway, TBL had to break down the protocol communications that occurred between the server and the client, resulting in the creation of (among many other things):

The DOCTYPE

The META tags

The TITLE tag

LINK tags and SCRIPT tags

Along with the content formatting tags like `<a>` tags, `<p>` tags, `<h1><h2><h etc>` tags, `<div>`s, etc

To compartmentalize the **document content** from the **protocol information**, TBL separated the `<head>` of an HTML document from the `<body>` - and he used these words so they would be easily understood as to their purpose.

So yes, perhaps a `<div>` tag could have been used in place of the `<body>` tag, and another `<div>` tag could probably even replace the `<head>` tag - but that is today, with our current knowledge and understanding of how HTML documents are used. But when they were first being developed, *in an age when computers were only beginning to talk to each other*, it was a different story. Consider how much the simple [`DOCTYPE` tag has evolved](http://nimbupani.com/the-truth-about-doctypes.html).

Here are some links with some fascinating reading:

[A history of HTML](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html)

[Global structure of an HTML document](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/struct/global.html)

[HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/)

[HTML Standard FAQ](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/master/FAQ.md)  *Interesting!*

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that HTML, especially at the beginning, was written by hand, and retains semantic meaning for *authors* as well as *machines*. The mindset has changed recently, with HTML dealt with nearly (or actually) as a compiled language, but that's not how it was. This is more broad than just `body`, though.